# How to parse JSON string without using any API?

Tags: parsing, ios4

I need to use the JSON parser in my iPhone application. We have API's which are used to parse the data.
I just want to know, how can we do without using any API ?

Thank you.

Comment: JSON parsing (in almost every programming language) has already been done before - why are you tormenting yourself trying to write your own?

Comment: 1. View the [specification for JSON](http://json.org/); 2. Start parsing at the `value`. 3. Knock yourself out with a state-based parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use the APIs.
2. Use the APIs.
3. Use the APIs.

They're quick, they've been tested to work, and you don't have to think about them.

If you're still committed to writing a JSON parser (and/or if this is an academic pursuit), then you're likely to benefit from researching the JSON specification and brushing up on [your platform of choice]'s string operations and regular expressions library.  Then, as [@alexanderb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662581/how-to-parse-json-string-without-using-any-api/4662653#4662653) suggests, create a small library of classes and/or functions to support you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Since JSON is a simple string, you could create your own parser that is able to serialize string to target object.

For instance, you have JSON like that

> { description: "my description", value: 10 }

You can extract description value, by regex and return object of class, like

```
class Target
{
   string Description;
   int value;
}
```

But, of cause it always a good idea to use time-proven JSON parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the 8k of these 238 lines (+/- comments) into your code:
http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/source/browse/trunk/src/json_sans_eval.js?r=12